# How to Deserialize XML Array items?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, deserialization

I am having trouble deserializing XML. I get AccountInformation to work but it won't work with the Leauge elements. The XML doesn't contain any tag for "Leauges" and I don't want to add that tag to get it to work. Is there any other way to "fix" it? I have tried diffrent solutions but the deserialized result of the leauges comes back empty. What am I missing?

Any help appreciated!

Se my code below:

*Update:*

I have modified the code and the XML but I won't work anyway. What am I missing here?

```c#
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "LeaugeCollection", Namespace = "")]
public class LeagueCollection
{
    [XmlArray("Leagues")]
    [XmlArrayItem("League",typeof(League))]
    public  League[] League { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AccountInformation")]
    public string AccountInformation { get; set; }

}

[Serializable()]
public class League
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Historical_Data")]
    public string Historical_Data { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fixtures")]
    public string Fixtures { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LiveScore")]
    public string Livescore { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "NumberOfMatches")]
    public int NumberOfMatches { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LatestMatch")]
    public DateTime LatestMatch { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize code:

```c#
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LeagueCollection));

        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\XmlFiles\XmlSoccer.xml");
        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        LeagueCollection XmlData = (LeagueCollection)obj;
        reader.Close();
    }
```

[Link to XML:](http://imagebin.ca/v/2B5fCJr1YvwP)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide the part of code where you do the deserialization, it would be easier to get help..

Comment: I forgot, have updated my the question

Comment: Is there any workaround when the leauges tag is missing? I would rather not add it manually because this is the reponse i get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML you have in the image is missing the actual array element (Leauges), it has only the array items elements (Leauge), that is why you cannot get it deserialized!

**UPDATE:**
Ok, trying to reproduce your code, I now see that in your XML your elements are spelled "League" while in your code "Leauge"

FIX that first!

**UPDATE2:**
After the edits you have done according to my comments,it seems to work fine!

Comment: I have tried adding the leauges tag but it didnt work anyway. Is there no other way to do it? I dont want to add tags cause this is the result from a response. Thanks

Comment: try to add a "Leauge" tag instead of "Leauges" to enclose the array items, it seems to be marked this way (maybe incorrectly).. note in your code `[XmlArray("Leauge")]`

Comment: Hi cmon, i have updated my question please have a look and see what im missing. Thankz

Comment: See my last update! you have mispelled League to Leauge in your code!!

Comment: Oh sorry, so similar text :/
I have updated the code. But now i get this InnerException:<LeagueCollection xmlns=''> was not expected.

Comment: Had LeagueCollection misspelled in the root :P 
Now it works. Thanks alot! Really appreciate it.

Comment: OK, after the edits you have done, i test your code and it is working!

Comment: Ok then, please do accept my answer as correct. Mark it with the "check"  and upvote with the up arrow (so I get the score for answering)

Comment: I dont have the amount of reputation to upvote, i would if i could. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a namespace.  I don't like both Leagues and League.  Leagues is unnecessary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LeagueCollection leagueCollection = new LeagueCollection() {
                leagues = new Leagues() {
                    League = new List<League>() {
                       new League() {
                          Id = 1,
                          Name = "English Premier League",
                          Country = "England",
                          Historical_Data = "Yes",
                          Fixtures = "Yes",
                          Livescore = "Yes",
                          NumberOfMatches = 5700,
                          LatestMatch = DateTime.Parse( "2015-05-24T16:00:00+00:00")
                    },
                        new League() {
                            Id = 2,
                            Name = "English League Championship",
                            Country = "England",
                            Historical_Data = "Yes",
                            Fixtures = "Yes",
                            Livescore = "Yes",
                            NumberOfMatches = 5700,
                            LatestMatch = DateTime.Parse("2015-05-24T16:00:00+00:00")
                        }
                    }

                },
                AccountInformation = "Confidential info"
            };


            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LeagueCollection));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, leagueCollection);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LeagueCollection));

            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            LeagueCollection XmlData = (LeagueCollection)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "LeaugeCollection")]
    public class LeagueCollection
    {
        [XmlElement("Leagues")]
        public Leagues leagues { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AccountInformation")]
        public string AccountInformation { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("Leagues")]
    public class Leagues
    {
        [XmlElement("League")]
        public List<League> League { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("League")]
    public class League
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Historical_Data")]
        public string Historical_Data { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fixtures")]
        public string Fixtures { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LiveScore")]
        public string Livescore { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "NumberOfMatches")]
        public int NumberOfMatches { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LatestMatch")]
        public DateTime LatestMatch { get; set; }
    }

}
​
​
```

Comment: I have already solved the problem,but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.